# Subjonctif en français et en anglais

Tags: anglais, subjonctif

La principale différence est qu'en anglais il est à peu près aussi utilisé que son imparfait en français. Mais pour ce qui est du choix de l'utilisation du subjonctif ou de l'indicatif, les règles semblent différer entre les deux langues. Quels en sont les principes généraux ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a general comparison of two moods, the English subjunctive and the French subjunctive, therefore it concerns a comparison of two languages.

Comment: Are only allowed demands concerning the translation of English terms but not of sentences or texts; for a limited question about the subjunctive, produce an instance of its use in English and ask for its translation; you can thus obtain a certain amount of compared information in the two grammars but never an extended account of the whole situation.

Comment: Pour les principes généraux en français, c'est trop pour une réponse sur Stack Exchange. Il faudrait consulter une grammaire, ou une encyclopédie pour un résumé. Nous pouvons répondre à des questions sur des cas plus restreints. Pour l'anglais, même remarque, et en plus c'est hors sujet ici.

Comment: @Gilles Sauf que les cas particuliers obtiennent généralement ici des réponses générales...

Comment: Similaire : https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/use-of-subjunctive-in-various-languages